# Jupyter note notebook is not giving token while starting

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Jupyter note notebook is not giving token while starting. I try to run it on cloud machine and since no token is given anyone having ip address:port can access it.

I start my notebook in docker image using

> jupyter notebook

Comment: Which `jupyter notebook` version do you use?

Comment: Thanks, I was using an older version at that time. Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

[Try this?](https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/datascience-notebook/)

I would recommend running Jupyter as its own docker container. With this you should just be able to do a `docker pull` and `docker run` with the correct commands